# Wordpress add_options_page capability problems

Tags: php, wordpress

Im new to wordpress plugining.
I got WP version 3.4.1, and im making a custom admin options plugin
Here is my code:

```
function caquacp_admin(){
include('caquacp_import_admin.php');
}
function caquacp_admin_actions() {
    add_options_page("Am User Panel", "User Panel", "admin", "User_Panel", "caquacp_admin");
}  
add_action('admin_menu', 'caquacp_admin_actions');
```

in capability string i tryied using: 'manage_options', "administrator", "admin", 0, 1, 8

Every time I get same error(Cant grant access)

Please help %)

Comment: Try with delete_users , create_user , activate_plugins ... also As @Libin says, did you login as an administrator?

Comment: of course i logged in as admin becouse im in admin menu ^^

Comment: tnx mate... delete_users did it ))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Try with delete_users , create_user , activate_plugins ... also As @Libin says, did you login as an administrator? – noc2spam

Tnx alot it solved my problem